# Swagger generating javascript-closure-angular-client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, closures, swagger

I am new to swagger, I have generated a javascript closure angular client from the swagger's online editor, it gave me a DefaultAPI.js and other JS files that match my objects definitions.

I've searched in swagger docs and on the net for a way to use the generated files in an angular application but didn't find any explanation, any clue ?

Comment: mmm, maybe you need this: https://github.com/olaferlandsen/angular-swagger2-client
This is a implementation of swagger 2.0 client for angular 1.4+

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. any update?

Comment: @harryfeng nop :( I've created my own generator to generate exactly what I want