# Generate javascript class/objects from a YAML

Tags: javascript, yaml, generator, code-generation, swagger

Is there any tool to generate JavaScript classes from a YAML ?

I have a swagger YAML and I want to generate javascript models that look like this :

```
'use strict';

function Product(name,description){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.toString = function(){
        return this.name+" : "+this.description;
}
```

}

using the swagger YAML :

```
.
.
.
definitions:
  product:
properties:
  name:
    type: string
  description:
    type: string
required:
  - name
  - description
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate JS API clients (with models), clients in other langauges (e.g. Ruby, Typescript, etc), server stubs (e.g. NodeJS, Java Spring, etc) and API documentation.

Given that you already have the OpenAPI/Swagger spec, you can do the following:

1. Go to https://editor.swagger.io
2. Select "File" in the top menu, then "Import File" to load your spec
3. Then select "Generate Client" in the top menu and click on "Javascript"

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: Yes, in fact I have already tried this and the angular generated code too, but I didn't know how to use the code generated and I didn't find a tutorial and I didn't find an answer to my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936437/swagger-generating-javascript-closure-angular-client